# How can I recursively iterate a date's digits and sum?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to **recursively iterate a date's digits**, sum them and then calculate another sum of the individual digits in the first sum.

For example,
DOB 15 August 1947 (15/08/1947)

1+5+0+8+1+9+4+7 = 35

3+5 = 8

**Answer: 8**

LINQ's `.Aggregate()` function helps me a lot...

```
DOB.toString().Aggregate((a,b)=>(int)a+(int)b)
```

...but it results **35 :(**

I want a recursive LINQ call with the result always being one digit.

Comment: its an result wen u more believe on System ..
Right its 8 thanks cuong

Answer (score 6):

```
string result = DOB.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

while (result.Length > 1)
    result = result.Sum(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))
                   .ToString();
```

Comment: True said ... :( but i want to Iterate by LINQ and Result should be in single Query/Line 
Simple by the power of LINQ..

Comment: can we Use While or condition in last line wen we sum up the Code

like result = result( Any Provision ).Sum(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToString();

Answer (score 2):

DOB.ToString("yyyymmdd") returns exactly 8 digits. Every digit doesn't exceed 9 so the first sum never exceeds 8*9=72. So just one another summation is needed. Finally the one-single-linq answer is:

```
sum =
       dob.ToString("yyymmdd")
          .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + int.Parse(b.ToString())).ToString()
          .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + int.Parse(b.ToString())).ToString()
          .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => p + int.Parse(b.ToString()));
```

Comment: There can be a maximum of 3 iterations. not 2. e.g. 
19/01/1999 => 39 => 12 => 3

Comment: I felt this one was the most Helpful..
with a Power of LINQ..
But failed on 3 Iterations or mre .

Comment: @EoinCampbell You are right. I amended the answer according to your correction.

Comment: @paramjeetsingh Please be advised that the answer is amended according to Eoin Campbell comment

Comment: @EoinCampbell Please provide some Generic,If No. should be generic or a long no. rather than a date(so hw can i Dynamically Control aggragate)..

Comment: @Alireza can i use any kind of Recursion heree.only by LINQ